# Can you help me in finding a trigger query including both tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables `labs` and `patients`. `labs` attributes are `lab_id`, `positive`, `negative` and `patients` attributes are `lab_id`, `test_result`.

I want to create a trigger to increment count of `positive` in `labs` table if the `test_result` inserted in `patients` is `positive` and `lab_id` is same, or increment count of `negative` in `labs` table if the `test_result` inserted in `patients` is `negative` and `lab_id` is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I didn't test this, because of mysql doesn't exists.

But I believe that this will help you, a bit.

> Update:  Error's been fixed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_after_insert_patients  
AFTER INSERT ON patients FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  UPDATE labs
  SET 
    positive = CASE WHEN NEW.test_result LIKE 'positive' THEN positive + 1 ELSE positive END,
    negative = CASE WHEN NEW.test_result LIKE 'negative' THEN negative + 1 ELSE negative END
  WHERE lab_id = NEW.lab_id;
END;//
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tested it and fixed. Please try it.